# Helm chart dependencies with variable registry

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am developing helm charts. Each of those charts has several dependencies which are declared as dependency in Chart.yaml. The registry field has to point an private registry. However, I have to deploy the chart on different environments that have different private registries available.
Currently, I have to create a helm chart for each environment in order to set the right registry for the dependency.

Example:

- Environment A

Chart.yaml of MyChart:

```
dependencies:
- name: aChart
 version: x.x.x
 repository: registryA
```

- Environment B

Chart.yaml of MyChart:

```
dependencies:
- name: aChart
 version: x.x.x
 repository: registryB
```

I would like to have MyChart only once and set/manipulate the repository field dynamically. Does anyone have an idea how I can accomplish that? Maybe kustomize?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `condition` to `enable/disable` dependencies chart
In `Chart.yaml` file will inclues several dependencies

```
dependencies:
- name: aChart
  version: x.x.x
  repository: registryA
  condition: aChart.enabled
  alias: aChart
- name: aChart
  version: x.x.x
  repository: registryB
  condition: bChart.enabled
  alias: bChart
```

Then, you can use this `chart` for whole environment and in file `values.yaml` for every environment will only enable necessary dependency.

For instance

`values-A.yaml`

```
aChart:
  enabled: true
  ...
  ...
  ...
bChart:
  enabled: false
```

`values-B.yaml`

```
aChart:
  enabled: false
bChart:
  enabled: true
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: I assume that this won't work since the name of the charts are the same. I think I could use alias for that, however, then I would need the value configuration for the dependency twice. Therefore, I think to keep the value files synchronous is too error prone.

Comment: You can use `alias`, if subcharts have the same name (as my updated answer). In addition, about using values files for each environment, you can use git to manage.

Comment: Yes, that is true. However, then it could be possible that internal URLs are different, since several helm charts, use the chart name (which is the alias), as part of service and pod names. Therefore, I still think that this approach is too error prone, even if I use git. It would be great if values like internal URLs (kubernetes internal) are the same for all environments.